# Spring MVС, Hibernate - получаю exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Используется Spring MVC и Hibernate, при создании сессии получаю исключение:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain
>   transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1013)
>   nikfisher.kickstarter.dao.QuoteDAO.quoteGenerate(QuoteDAO.java:34)
>   nikfisher.kickstarter.controller.MainController.index(MainController.java:18)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

application-context.xml :

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<!--<tx:annotation-driven/>-->

<context:component-scan base-package="nikfisher.kickstarter"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="nikfisher.kickstarter.domain"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">nikfisher.kickstarter.dialect.SQLiteDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:D:/Dzvene/Projects/kickstarter/src/main/resources/kickstarter.db" />
    <property name="username" value=""/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="quoteDAO" class="nikfisher.kickstarter.dao.QuoteDAO" />
```

DAO :

```
@Service
public class QuoteDAO {

    private final static org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QuoteDAO.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public String quoteGenerate() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from Quote");
        List<Quote> motivators = query.list();
        int index = new Random().nextInt(motivators.size());
        return motivators.get(index).getQuote();
    }

    protected Session getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Доменная модель :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "quote")
public class Quote {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "quote", nullable = false)
    private String quote;

    public String getQuote() {
        return quote;
    }

    public void setQuote(String quote) {
        this.quote = quote;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Контроллер :

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private QuoteDAO quoteDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("item", quoteDAO.quoteGenerate());
        return "pages/index";
    }
}
```